# Multi-stage build just loading last part?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm new with docker and I'm pretty sure this must be a silly mistake (sorry in advance), but I'm trying to combine some images. The first one is to install a software (TEtranscripts), and the second one I just want to have it as it is (cellranger). Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda
RUN conda install -c bioconda tetranscripts

FROM marcusczi/cellranger_clean
COPY --from=marcusczi/cellranger_clean / /
```

I don't get any errors when building this (`docker build --tag tecell .`), but when i run it (docker run -i -t --name tecell tecell) only cellranger is available. If i switch places like:

```
FROM marcusczi/cellranger_clean
COPY --from=marcusczi/cellranger_clean / /

FROM continuumio/anaconda
RUN conda install -c bioconda tetranscripts
```

Just TEtranscripts is available.

I was checking the [official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) about it and I notice they built the app before passing to the next `FROM` statement, so I'm guessing is something like that but I would like some explanation on how/why to use it.

Thank you so much in advance! :-)

Comment: In general, you can't combine two Docker images this way.  If, for example, they're not built on the same version of Python, the `python3.8` in one image won't find the `/usr/lib/python3.7/...` files from the other image.  You probably need to pick _one_ image to start from, and use tools like `pip` to install your library dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the observation David. I will make sure to address this somehow :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `COPY --from` is wrong. You should reference the other build-step instead.

Like that: `FROM continuumio/anaconda as firststep` and `COPY --from=firststep`

So your Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda as firststep
RUN conda install -c bioconda tetranscripts

FROM marcusczi/cellranger_clean
COPY --from=firststep / /
```

Comment: This is likely to have very bizarre side effects, especially if the two images aren't built on the same core Linux distribution.

Comment: Surely, but that is out of scope of the question AFAIK.

Comment: This solved my problem and it's pretty easy to follow, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is a multi stage build.

You want to build the app in the first image and then copy the built app from the first image into a second image that will actually run the app.

You are missing the

```
COPY --from=0
```

You can either name your stages and then refer then using the names(@Michée Lengronne already explained in his answer that approach), or you can use `--from=0` to refer at the image built in the first step.